# Changing background color on scroll with javascript

Tags: javascript, scroll, colors, background, sections

https://codepen.io/tobiasthaden/pen/OVWKjm

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  $('section').each(function(i) {
    if ($(this).position().top <= $(window).scrollTop()) {
      $('body').css('background-color', $(this).attr('data-color'));
    }
  });
});
```

Looking to replicate this effect using regular old javascript. I don’t want to use jQuery!

Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have done it like this.

```js
const sections = document.querySelectorAll('section')

document.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  sections.forEach(section => {
    if(section.getBoundingClientRect().top <= document.body.scrollTop) {
      document.body.style.background = section.dataset.color
    }    
  })
})
```

```css
body {
  transition: background-color .2s ease;
}

section {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<section data-color="white"></section>
<section data-color="green"></section>
<section data-color="purple"></section>
<section data-color="yellow"></section>
<section data-color="blue"></section>
<section data-color="white"></section>
```

Comment: Say you wanted the first section to be a color other than white. How would this work?

Answer (score 1):

```js
    const sections = document.querySelectorAll('section')
    
    window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
        sections.forEach(section => {
            const distFromTop = document.body.scrollTop + section.getBoundingClientRect().top
            if (distFromTop < 10) {
                document.body.style.background = section.dataset.color
            }
        })
    })
```

```css
        body {
            transition: background-color .2s ease;
        }

        section {
            height: 100vh;
        }
```

```html
    <section data-color="white"></section>
    <section data-color="green"></section>
    <section data-color="purple"></section>
    <section data-color="yellow"></section>
    <section data-color="blue"></section>
    <section data-color="white"></section>
```

This seems to work well enough!

Comment: Say you wanted the first section to be a color other than white. How would this work?